# Cannot execute RUN mkdir in a Dockerfile

Tags: docker

This is an error message I get when building a Docker image:

```
Step 18 : RUN mkdir /var/www/app && chown luqo33:www-data /var/www/app
---> Running in 7b5854406120 mkdir: cannot create directory '/var/www/app': No such file or directory
```

This is a fragment of Dockerfile that causes the error:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
RUN groupadd -r luqo33 && useradd -r -g luqo33 luqo33

<installing nginx, fpm, php and a couple of other things>

RUN mkdir /var/www/app && chown luqo33:www-data /var/www/app
VOLUME /var/www/app
WORKDIR /var/www/app
```

`mkdir: cannot create directory '/var/www/app': No such file or directory` sound so nonsensical - of course there is no such directory. I want to create it. What is wrong here?

Comment: Nothing Docker-specific here, btw -- you'd have the same problem running `mkdir /var/www/app` on a system that didn't have a `/var/www` without it.

Answer (score 244, accepted):

The problem is that `/var/www` doesn't exist either, and `mkdir` isn't recursive by default -- it expects the immediate parent directory to exist.

Use:

```
mkdir -p /var/www/app
```

...or install a package that creates a `/var/www` prior to reaching this point in your Dockerfile.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. By the way, what package do you mean that would create `/var/www` ?

Comment: That's a question about Ubuntu 14.04 packaging; I'm not an expert there.

Comment: I am already doing that `RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app` and fails

Comment: @KristiJorgji, ... `/usr/src/app` is not `/var/www/app`. In general, when you have a problem different enough that existing questions' answers can't be applied, ask a new question (with a proper [mre], showing how you tried to apply those existing questions' answers, and how those attempts failed, to prevent your new question from being closed as duplicative).

Answer (score 80):

When creating subdirectories hanging off from a non-existing parent directory(s) you must pass the `-p` flag to `mkdir` ... Please update your Dockerfile with

```
RUN mkdir -p ...
```

I tested this and it's correct.

Answer (score 32):

You can also simply use

```
WORKDIR /var/www/app
```

It will automatically create the folders if they don't exist.

Then switch back to the directory you need to be in.

Comment: "I wonder why we switch to this working directory only to switch away from it again in the next line? It must be some stale code let me clean up this docker file" use `mkdir`, it was made for the job of making directories ;)

Comment: Sometimes you want to create a directory without it being your workdir..

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the previous use cases, you can also use [Docker Compose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_%28software%29#Tools) to create directories in case you want to make new dummy folders on `docker-compose up`:

```
    volumes:
  - .:/ftp/
  - /ftp/node_modules
  - /ftp/files
```

Comment: What is the matter with this answer? [Helzgate's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30741995/docker-cannot-execute-run-mkdir-in-a-dockerfile/57577358#57577358) was also late.

Comment: @PeterMortensen The question is about Dockerfile, not about docker-compose.

Comment: The question is about Dockerfile..

Answer (score 1):

Also if you want to use multiple directories and then their change owner, you can use:

```
RUN set -ex && bash -c 'mkdir -p /var/www/{app1,app2}' && bash -c 'chown luqo33:www-data /var/www/{app1,app2}'
```

Just this!

Comment: Why would you use a separate `bash -c` per command? Wouldn't `RUN bash -exc 'mkdir -p /var/www/app{1,2} && chown luqo33:www-data /var/www/app{1,2}'` be much more efficient?